# Why is hair not displaying in render viewport but displays in solid view (while in object mode)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

Solid view looks as such:

[image]

But rendered view is unable to produce hair:

[image]

You can see the hair displays on the simple sphere, making me think there is something wrong with the lower mesh, however I can not find any discrepancies between the two. Both have the same materials and normal's are fine.

Blend file here:
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51690

Comment: Hair thickness is too small so that you can't see hairs in the render mode. Go to "Cycles Hair Settings" of the particles and there is "Scaling" option, increases it to a higher number 1 or 2 as you want.

Comment: @3DSinghVFX Awesome, that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hair thickness is too small so that you can't see hairs in the render mode. Go to "Cycles Hair Settings" of the particles and there is "Scaling" option, increases it to a higher number 1 or 2 as you want. – 3DSinghVFX

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a situation where hair would show perfectly in the viewport render preview but not in an actual render with blender 2.9 cycles. ***The cause: the hair dynamics checkbox was unchecked.***